# Connection error while retrieving metada from container running an ECS task

Tags: docker, networking, boto3, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk

I'm trying to retrieve the actual region where the instance running the ECS task in a container is. The container runs a python script which first task is to get the region so that I can use boto3 methods like `sqs.get_queue_by_name()` which need a region to be set. To do that, I try to get the region with

```
meta = requests.get('http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document', timeout=1).json()
os.environ["AWS_DEFAULT_REGION"] = meta.get("region")
```

but I got a connection error.

When I build my stack by hand, there is no issue, but when the stack is deployed by CDK (the the same security groups, roles etc), I got the error

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='169.254.169.254', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fe3d62491f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 22] Invalid argument'))
```

I can see two different avenues to solve this issue:

- Set the environment variable 'AWS_DEFAULT_REGION' when deploying with CDK, but with

  taskDefinition.addContainer('DSPTContainer', {
          image: ecrImage,
          memoryLimitMiB: 30000,
          environment: {
              AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: props.env?.region
          })
  there is an issue with `Property 'AWS_DEFAULT_REGION' is incompatible with index signature.`
- Modifying the task role (but how) or something else (like the security group) to allow the connection. Note that within the instance, I am able to establish the connection....

**[EDIT]**

Inside the container (I can log into container when instance is running), I can ping say google.com but not the instance metadata URI:

```
import requests
requests.get("https://www.google.com", timeout=1) ---> Response200
requests.get("http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/", timeout=1) ---> ConnectTimeout Exception
```

**[SOLUTION]**

Issue linked to [duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62480915/how-can-an-ecs-task-know-in-which-region-is-runs)