# How can an ECS task know in which region is runs?

Tags: amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-ecs

I have a python application using boto3 in a task launched by ECS (in a docker container). The boto3 command I use need a region to work properly, but I only know the region at runtime (multi-region application). The idea was then to define the `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` environment variable by retrieving the region in the dynamic document provided by Amazon from URI http://169.254.169.254. However, whereas the call works fine from the instance, I cannot access the endpoint from within the task container.

Is there a clean way to know in which region the task actually runs ?

**[SOLUTION]**

Have a look at the issue [enter link description here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/8664)

Comment: Are after [ECS metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-metadata-endpoint.html) which is similar to EC2 metadata that you are trying to query?

Comment: There is `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` already provided for [tasks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-config.html). Thus you should not need to query instance metadata for that.

Comment: @Marcin, that's what I thought, however the first line of my python task checks if the `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` is populated and if it's not, retrieve it. I haven't verify if the fix provides the env variable or make metadata accessible with URI